# Gap between buttons on chrome

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap to create a btn-group, acting as radio buttons (javascript component).

This looks great in firefox, but there's a gap in chrome :

[image]

Is this a bug or do I have some extra markup somewhere ?

HTML code :

```
        <div id="loadOptions">
            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
                <button type="button" value="0" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button">All hashtags</button>
                <button type="button" value="1" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button" id="any">Any hashtag</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: The problem is there even if I remove all my css and keep bootstrap only. It's a custom download, maybe I'm missing something ?

Comment: Just a theory, but it could be caused by the newline and space characters in your markup between the buttons. Try placing each of the <button> tags after each other without any spaces or newlines.

Comment: I tried, but I still get the gap :(

Comment: I'm using Chrome with the latest version of TBS and don't see the problem (http://jsfiddle.net/technotarek/DWcG9/). Do you have any of your own CSS? If so, that's probably where the problem is coming from...

Comment: Just a theory, maybe it is because I don't have the full bootstrap but just the buttons components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem with :

```
button
{
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't press enter and put second button tag in front of first button tag, the gap will disappear :

```
<div id="loadOptions">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
        <button type="button" value="0" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button">All hashtags</button><button type="button" value="1" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button" id="any">Any hashtag</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, as mentioned in comments.